# Is it possible to display multiple icons in a single AG Grid cell and then be able to filter rows on each individual icon?

Tags: ag-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yea7b.png)

So would I be able to display multiple icons here and if so would the user be able to filter the grid rows to display rows that feature each icon (alone and as part of a group) by selecting each icon in the filter?

And could users tap the icons to open a detail grid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this sample which implements your use case: https://plnkr.co/edit/kEDrnyfBkoFoxFGB

You can display multiple icons on a row by using cellRenderers, first you have to provide it to the grid:

```
  columnDefs: [
    // group cell renderer needed for expand / collapse icons
    {
      field: 'name',
      minWidth: 300,
      cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
      cellRendererParams: {
        innerRenderer: 'iconRenderer',
      },
    },
  ],
  components: {
    iconRenderer: IconCellRenderer,
  },
};
```

Here is the Cell Renderer Component:

```
class IconCellRenderer {
  init(params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    this.eFilterButton = document.createElement('button');
    this.eExpandButton = document.createElement('button');
    this.eText = document.createElement('span');

    this.eText.textContent = params.value;
    this.eFilterButton.textContent = 'filter';
    this.eExpandButton.textContent = 'expand';

    this.eGui.appendChild(this.eText);
    this.eGui.appendChild(this.eFilterButton);
    this.eGui.appendChild(this.eExpandButton);

    this.eFilterButton.addEventListener('click', this.filterOnClick.bind(this));

    this.eExpandButton.addEventListener('click', this.expandOnClick.bind(this));
  }

  getGui() {
    return this.eGui;
  }

  expandOnClick(ev) {
    const isExpanded = this.params.node.expanded; 
    this.params.node.setExpanded(!isExpanded)
  }

  filterOnClick(ev) {
    const value = this.params.value;
    this.params.api.setFilterModel({
      name: { values: [value] },
    });
  }
}
```

The key here is that we can expand a row by calling `api.setExpanded(true)` on a node. And we can filter on the grid by calling `api.setFilterModel(filterModel)`